# How to send information to parent Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have `Fragment A` created by `MainActivity`. Inside this `Fragment A` is `container View`. I can create another `Fragment B` inside `Fragment A` and put it to this container.

What I want to achieve is send information (String) back to `Fragment A` from `Fragment B`.

Is this somehow possible, because the only option I have found is to recreate `Fragment A`, but this will make duplicate of old `Fragment A` and its content. Fragment A(first) and Fragment A(second) are on top of each other and this can cause serious memory issues if you repeat this process over and over.

Example of creating `Fragment B` inside `Fragment A`:

```
fragmentManager?.let { fm ->
                val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
                val sh = FragmentB(info)
                fragB = sh
                ft.add(R.id.container, sh)
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
            }
```

Exiting `Fragment B` and starting `Fragment A` again:

```
mainActivity?.startFragment(FragmentA(item.js.toString()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fragment A you should use `childFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager`

```
childFragmentManager.let { fm ->
                val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
                val sh = FragmentB(info)
                fragB = sh
                ft.add(R.id.container, sh)
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
            }
```

Inside fragment B you can get the reference to fragment A by

```
(parentFragment as FragmentA).someMethod()
```

Comment: I just used fragmentManager to remove this child fragment instead childFragmentManager. Forgot to change variable in remove function

Comment: Ok, final you did it :D